# The effect on expectation of biasing a distribution by a monotonic function

Tags: probability, expected-value, moments, integral, mathematical-statistics

Let 
$$ x \sim g(x)$$
where $g(x)$ denotes the pdf of $x$. Let the pdf of another variable $x^*$ be denoted by $f(x^*)$ and let 
$$f(x^*) \propto g(x^*) z(x^*) $$ 
where $z(x^*)$ is a monotonic increasing function.

It seems to me intuitively that, provided they are well defined, $E(x^*) \geq E(x)$. How can one prove (or disprove) this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer is motivated by the fact that the difference in expected values of two random variables is the (signed) area between their cumulative distribution functions (CDFs):

[image: Figure]

*In this figure, the expected value of $F$ exceeds that of $G$ by the area between the curves.  This is proven in an appendix below.*

**The plan,** then, is to demonstrate that the non-decreasing ratio of the densities of $X^{*}$ and $X$ implies the CDF of the first lies below the CDF of the second, implying the difference in expectations is positive.

The crux of the matter is to show that initially $F$ increases more slowly than $G$ (at the left), where both begin (asymptotically) at the same level of $0.$  The same thing happens at the right, where $F$ *drops more quickly* than $G$ from right to left, although both begin (asymptotically) at the same height of $1.$  They meet somewhere in the middle, but along the way $G$ has never been lower than $F.$

---

Begin with the basic inequality

$$\int u(x)\,\mathrm{d}x \ge 0$$

for all almost everywhere non-negative functions $u.$ This inequality will be invoked several times--watch for it.

When $u$ and $v$ are functions with $u(x)\ge v(x)$ for all $x,$ applying the inequality to their difference shows

$$\int u(x)\,\mathrm{d}x \ge \int v(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{*}$$

with equality only when $u(x)=v(x)$ almost everywhere.

Turning to the setting of the question, observe that since

$$\int g(x)\,\mathrm{d}x = 1 = \int z(x)g(x)\,\mathrm{d}x,$$

it is not possible for $z(x) \lt 1$ or $z(x)\gt 1$ for all $x$, because then $(*)$ would imply $1 \ne 1$ in either case.  **Therefore there exists an $x_0$ at which $z$ crosses $1:$**

$$z(x) \le 1\text{ for }x \le x_0\,\text{ and }\, z(x) \ge 1\text{ for }x \ge x_0.$$

Since $g(x)\ge 0$ everywhere, this implies

$$z(x)g(x) \le g(x)\text{ for }x \le x_0\,\text{ and }\, z(x)g(x) \ge g(x)\text{ for }x \ge x_0.$$

Define

$$G(x) = \int^x_{-\infty} g(t)\,\mathrm{d}t$$

and

$$F(x) = \int^x_{-\infty} z(t)g(t)\,\mathrm{d}t.$$

It is immediate from the inequality $(*)$ applied to the functions $u=g$ and $v(x)=z(x)g(x)$ that for all $x\le x_0$

$$G(x)\ge F(x)$$

and for all $x \ge x_0$

$$1 - F(x) = \int_x^\infty z(t)g(t)\,\mathrm{d}t \ge \int_x^\infty g(t)\,\mathrm{d}t = 1 - G(x),$$

whence for *all* $x,$

$$G(x)\ge F(x).$$

But now

$$E[X^*] - E[X] = \int_{-\infty}^\infty (G(x)-F(x))\,\mathrm{d}x \ge 0,$$

*QED.*

---

If the final expression for the difference of expectations surprised you, note that (writing $f(x)=z(x)g(x)$) an integration by parts gives

$$\eqalign{
E[X^*] - E[X] &= \int x\,f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x -  \int x\,g(x)\,\mathrm{d}x \\
&=  \int x\,(f(x)-g(x))\,\mathrm{d}x \\
&= \left. x(F(x)-G(x))\right|_{-\infty}^\infty + \int_{-\infty}^\infty (G(x)-F(x))\,\mathrm{d}x
}$$

and

$$\left. x(F(x)-G(x))\right|_{-\infty}^\infty = \lim_{x\to\infty,y\to-\infty} \left[x(F(x)-G(x)) - y(F(y)-G(y))\right] = 0 - 0 = 0$$

provided both expectations exist and are finite.

---

**This demonstration applies more generally**, and with no change at all, to the situation where $X^{*}$ has a distribution $\mathrm{d}\lambda$ that is absolutely continuous with respect to the distribution $\mathrm{d}\nu$ of $X$ and its Radon-Nikodym derivative $z = \mathrm{d}\lambda / \mathrm{d}\nu$ is a non-decreasing function.  This has applications to discrete distribution families like the Poisson distribution.  The concept goes by the name "Monotone Likelihood Ratio."

**Another generalization** applies to the expectations of any nondecreasing function of $X:$ at the end you arrive at the integral of the (generalized) derivative of that function, multiplied by $G(x)-F(x),$ which again must give a non-negative result.